# Custom expression

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I found this example code:

```
public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(ObjectSet<T> obj) where T : class
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var x = type.GetInterface("IMyInterface");

    if (x != null)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty("MyStringField");
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "it");
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate =
            (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property),
                    Expression.Constant("MyValue")),
                parameter);
        //...
    }
}
```

What I really need is to apply a StartsWith condition (`StartsWith("MyValue")`) and apply another condition like >= for my another `int?` property.

How can I modify the code to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
 Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.Call(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property),
                typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) }),
                Expression.Constant("MyValue")), parameter);
```

Comment: great..and to apply a GreaterThanOrEqual?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, consider what expression this expression tree represents.

```
var property = type.GetProperty("MyStringField");
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "it");
Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate =
    (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property),
            Expression.Constant("MyValue")),
        parameter);
```

is equivalent to the lambda:

```
it => it.MyStringField == "MyValue"
```

So what would you like the expression be then?  From what I understand you wrote, you want something like this:

```
it => it.MyStringField.StartsWith("MyValue") && it.MyNullableIntField >= 12
```

Well you can write this lambda and store it in an expression that way you can let the compiler perform the conversion for you:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate =
    it => it.MyStringField.StartsWith("MyValue") && it.MyNullableIntField >= 12;
```

Otherwise, doing it by hand:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "it");
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Property(parameter, "MyStringField"),
            "StartsWith",
            null,
            Expression.Constant("MyValue")
        ),
        Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
            Expression.Property(parameter, "MyNullableIntField"),
            Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(12), typeof(int?))
        )
    ),
    parameter
);
```

Comment: yeah...you are great :) just only one issue: the following generate an error at compiler time: Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = it => it.MyStringField.StartsWith("MyValue") && it.MyNullableIntField >= 12; (MyStringField not found..) ..so I did it by hand as yuo suggested.

Comment: @bit: The thing is, if you let the compiler do it, it will do type checking for you.  In general, it's ok to do that as long as you know what types are involved.  Since this is from within a generic method, we wouldn't be able to do that without the right constraints on the type.  However you probably won't have to deal with this case most of the time so use it when you can.